# How to lock a navigation drawer when another one is open

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I've got two navigation drawers on my view. I'd like to lock the left drawer when the right one is open, and I'd like to lock the right drawer when the left one is open.

As it stands, when (for example) the left one is open, and you swipe from the right to close it, the right drawer begins to open before the left one is fully closed. This is not desirable behavior.

Here's what I've tried, but am getting a `NullPointerException` when I swipe a drawer.

```
// Left Drawer Config
_leftDrawerToggler = new DrawerToggler(this,
                                       _rootViewLayout,
                                       Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_light,
                                       Resource.String.drawer_open,
                                       Resource.String.drawer_close);

_leftDrawerToggler.DrawerClosed += delegate
    {
        InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        _rootViewLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked, _rightDrawerLayout);
    };

_leftDrawerToggler.DrawerOpened += delegate
{
    _leftDrawerList.SetItemChecked(0, true);
    InvalidateOptionsMenu();
    _rootViewLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed, _rightDrawerLayout);
};

_rootViewLayout.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Left);
_rootViewLayout.SetDrawerListener(_leftDrawerToggler);



// Right Drawer Config
_rightDrawerToggler = new DrawerToggler(this,
                                       _rootViewLayout,
                                       Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_light,
                                       Resource.String.drawer_open,
                                       Resource.String.drawer_close);

_rightDrawerToggler.DrawerClosed += delegate
    {
        InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        _rootViewLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked, _leftDrawerLayout);
    };
_rightDrawerToggler.DrawerOpened += delegate
{
    _rightDrawerList.SetItemChecked(0, true);
    InvalidateOptionsMenu();
    _rootViewLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed, _leftDrawerLayout);
};

_rootViewLayout.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.right_drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Right);
_rootViewLayout.SetDrawerListener(_rightDrawerToggler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that **your not Locking the right** `VieW`. The other issue is you need to have only one `Listener` for the `DrawerLayout`. From your code i could understand your have two listener for the `DrawerLayout`

Your `Layout` `XML` should have a `DrawerLayout` with two `ListView` (`layout_gravity` for ListView should be `start` for one and the other `end` )

When the `Drawer` is `opened` check if the `View Object` is equal `View.equal()` , then lock the other `ListView' and when the 'Drawer` is `closed` unlock the other `ListView`.

Change you code like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mLeftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mRightDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view){
            if(view.equals(mRightDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mLeftDrawerList);
            }
            else {
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mRightDrawerList);
            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            if(view.equals(mRightDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, mLeftDrawerList);
            }
            else {
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, mRightDrawerList);
            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

This should work. Let me know if you see any issue.

Comment: That did it. I just added this into my DrawerToggler helper class and added the `_leftLayout` and `_rightLayout` to an overload constructor. Works like a champ!